# Checkout personalizado

Tags: c#, mercadopago, restsharp

Estoy haciendo un checkout personalizado por la API de MercadoPago y al enviarle estos datos me devuelve el error:

> ```
> transaction_amount attributte can´t be null.
> ```

```
var token = Authenticate();

var client = new RestClient(_restClient);

var request = new RestRequest("v1/payments", Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("access_token", token.access_token);
request.AddParameter("Public_key", Config.GetPublicKey(_mode));
request.AddParameter("currency_id", "ARS");
request.AddParameter("transaction_amount", 100);
request.AddParameter("description", "Compra nº 1");
request.AddParameter("installments", 1);
request.AddParameter("payment_method_id", "visa");

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Si, ya lo edite y sigue persistiendo el mismo error. Lo raro es que puedo poner cualquier dato y aún así me va a marcar que "transaction_amount" es nulo.

Comment: ya como intento desesperado, probaste mandarle un string ahi en lugar de un numero? y especificarle el tipo de parametro? y estas usando restsharp no?

Comment: Si, estoy usando RestSharp. Intente también pasarle un string pero no le pase el tipo. Si yo intento pasarle esta línea, me da error el int.

`request.AddParameter("transaction_amount", "100", int);`

Comment: vos @gbianchi como se lo madarías como string?

Comment: creo que probando no perdes nada.. pero no se mucho mas de lo que estamos hablando...

Comment: Si, ya probé y sigue el error, gracias igual.

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta todo lo que probaste.. tal vez tengas suerte..

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Hola! Al final probé directamente con el SDK doNet que ofrece MercadoPago. Pero ahora me da el error 500 - "Internal Error".